# ankushsachdeva emojicon display over softkeyboard (Android)

Tags: android, chat, overlay, android-softkeyboard, emoji

I implemented the [ankushsachdeva emojicon project](https://github.com/ankushsachdeva/emojicon) to display emojicons in my chat app. When i click on a specific chat i start my ChatActivity. If i then **immediately** click the emoji-imageButton which i made, without expanding the keyboard first, it looks like the left screenshot [here](http://postimg.org/image/wh9fqs1dz/fd90b616/)

Afterwords, the emojicon-overlay is **always** displayed correctly. (right screenshot)

I want the overlay to always be like in the right screenshot. Any ideas? (thanks in advance)

**ChatActivity:**

```
private ListView listView; //contains the chatmessages and has a customAdapter 
private EmojiconsPopup popUp; //emojicon-popUp
private EditText editText; //editText to capture text and emojicons
private InputMethodManager inputManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    //...//

    inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

    popUp = new EmojiconsPopup(listView, getApplicationContext());

    popUp.setSizeForSoftKeyboard();

    popUp.setOnEmojiconClickedListener(new OnEmojiconClickedListener(){
        @Override
        public void onEmojiconClicked(Emojicon emojicon){
            editText.append(emojicon.getEmoji());
        }
    });


    popUp.setOnEmojiconBackspaceClickedListener(new OnEmojiconBackspaceClickedListener(){
        @Override
        public void onEmojiconBackspaceClicked(View v){
            KeyEvent event = new KeyEvent(0, 0, 0, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL, 0, 0, 0, 0, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENDCALL);
            editText.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
        }
    });

    popUp.setOnSoftKeyboardOpenCloseListener(new OnSoftKeyboardOpenCloseListener(){
        @Override
        public void onKeyboardOpen(int keyBoardHeight){
        }
        @Override
        public void onKeyboardClose(){
            if (popUp.isShowing())
                popUp.dismiss();
        }
    });
}

//called when the emojicon button is clicked
public void onEmojiButtonClicked(View view){
    if (!popUp.isShowing()){
        inputManager.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
        popUp.showAtBottom(); //show popUp with emojicons
    }else if(popUp.isShowing()){
        popUp.dismiss(); // hide popUp with emojicons
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, there is no reliable way to know the soft keyboard height, the library calculates it by opening the keyboard and seeing how much the top most layout of the view heirarchy shrinks.

I have added a new function into the library showAtBottomPending() which should solve your problem. 
Make the following two changes to your code.

1. Change your onEmojiButtonClicked function to

   ```
   public void onEmojiButtonClicked(View view){
       if (!popUp.isShowing()){
           popUp.showAtBottomPending(); //show popUp with emojicons after the keyboard is visible
           inputManager.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
       }else if(popUp.isShowing()){
           popUp.dismiss(); // hide popUp with emojicons
       }
   }
   ```
2. Instead of passing listView in the EmojiconsPopup constructor,
   pass the top most layout of your view hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

use like this its working.

```
public void onEmojiButtonClicked(View view){
if (!popUp.isShowing()){
    popUp.showAtBottomPending(); //show popUp with emojicons after the keyboard is visible
    showKeyboard(ettext);
}else if(popUp.isShowing()){
    popUp.dismiss(); // hide popUp with emojicons
}
}


public void showKeyboard(final EmojiconEditText ettext){
          ettext.requestFocus();
          ettext.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            @Override public void run(){
              InputMethodManager keyboard=(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
              keyboard.showSoftInput(ettext,0);
            }
          }
        ,200);
        }
```